# Eigen Dynamic Matrix with Max-Size at Compile Time: Stack or Heap?

Tags: eigen

If I declare a matrix via

```
Eigen::Matrix<int,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::ColMajor,128,128> myMat;
```

will it be allocated on the stack or on the heap? Is there a simple way to force such a matrix to be on the heap?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by specifying the maximum size if not stack-allocation?

Comment: I have a pool of objects. At run-time, my program requests new objects from the pool and discards used objects back to the pool, dynamically. Each of these objects has a few Eigen matrices as members but for simplicity, let's just assume here that each of said objects have just one Eigen matrix as member...

Comment: ...After a new object is requested, a configuration function sets up the object before it is put to use. Setting up the object involves .resize() of said matrix: some objects will have a matrix of size X, some other of size Y, etc. but never above size Z....

Comment: ...Since the requesting/discarding happens often, using the classic Eigen Dynamic (unknown size at compile time) will lead to fragmentation and therefore performance will degrade. I want to have objects of known size at compile time. The above line does the trick, but I am not sure whether having said matrix as a member of an object will mess things up in the stack.